# Multiple repeat error when searching for a string in a larger string in dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have two dataframes, one with the content of a PDF and metadata (total 5000 rows):

```
PDF_title    Content                  Author    Year
a            this is cleaned which... Pete      2009
b            a pdf about some topi... John      2006
c            here is another artic... Tom       1997
etc.
```

and one with labels (total 5100 rows):

```
Item                     Label
9308                     hello
837_c                    pdf some
2982                     another article
2_hic                    this cleaned which
2829_d                   another label
etc.
```

I would like to find the number of times that the label occurs in the content. As the labels sometimes do not EXACTLY match part of the content, but have words in between, I thought of the following regex to match the pattern (5 being subjective):

```
pat = "\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,5}?"
```

Imagine if 'this cleaned which' (2_hic) would occur 4 times in PDF a, et cetera, I would like my outcome to be something like the following, only printing counts > 0:

```
a
2_hic: 4
9308: 7

b
837_c: 2

c
2982: 6
```

Right now, I tried the following, but I get a 'multiple repeat' error. I know it has something to do with the regex, but I'm not sure how to solve it!

```
df2['Label_regex'] = df2['Label'].str.replace(" ", pat)

tup_df1 = [tuple(x) for x in df1.values]
tup_df1 = [tuple(map(str,eachTuple)) for eachTuple in tup_df1]

tup_df2 = [tuple(x) for x in df2.values]
tup_df2 = [tuple(map(str,eachTuple)) for eachTuple in tup_df2] 

result = []
for doc in tup_df1:
    doc_result = []
    for con in tup_df2:
        length = len(re.findall(con[2], doc[1]))
        if 0<length:          
            doc_result.append((con[1], length))
    if doc_result:
        result.append((doc[0],doc_result))

for i in result:
    print i[0]
    for j in i[1]:
        print '\t{}: {}'.format(j[0],j[1])
```

Running it, as I said, gives me a 'multiple repeat' error. I hope I have explained myself clearly. I am quite new to Python, so any feedback is welcome :-)